# How to show decimals with 0 in chartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

So I am trying to achieve a standard behaviour through out my chart.

And that can be achieved if ChartJS won't remove 0 decimal places

**EXAMPLE:** ChartJS will consider 19.0 as 19 there by removing .0.

`12.1, 19.0, 3.4`

**REQUIREMENT**

> chartJS to retain 19.0 as it is and do not remove .0

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-tutorial-forked-4pluiv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your example doesn't appear to show any decimals, but there's a good chance it's just JS removing the decimals if they are stored as numbers, have you looked into using formatter to produce a string output?

Comment: @DBS The requirement is to not convert to string. I have updated my codesandbox link

Comment: A number in JS will never have `.0` after it when displayed, it is simplified automatically. If you want to show the `.0`, the label has to be a string (all the data and layout would look the same, it's just the variables type).

Comment: @DBS I see, but how to do I achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to format your tooltips value as a string, this can be achieved by adding a [label formatter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) using `.toFixed()` ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)) into the options:

```
plugins: {
  tooltip: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(context) {
        // This guarantees that 1 decimal place is shown
        return context.parsed.y.toFixed(1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Forked version of your codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-tutorial-forked-cub1mn) showing this in action.